# How to measure C++ or Java file complexity?

Tags: java, c++, code-metrics, cyclomatic-complexity, churn

I want to start measuring what Michael Feathers has referred to as the turbulence of code, namely [churn vs. complexity](http://www.stickyminds.com/sitewide.asp?Function=edetail&ObjectType=COL&ObjectId=16679&tth=DYN&tt=siteemail&iDyn=2).

To do this, I need to measure the complexity of a C++ or Java file.  So I found a couple tools that measure cyclomatic complexity (CC).  They each measure CC well at the function or method level.  However, I need a metric at the file level, and they don't do so well there.  One tool just returns the average of all method complexities in the file, and the other tool treats the whole file like it is one giant method, i.e., it counts all the decision points in the whole file.

So I did some research and found that McCabe defines CC only in terms of modules--and they define a module as a function--not as a file (see slides 20 and 30 of [this presentation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rivier.edu%2Ffaculty%2Fvriabov%2FCS699_McCabe_Overview.ppt&ei=o8NMUtikC4TCywG4p4DAAQ&usg=AFQjCNH_KmduonpB78Wbx4LJuc5gfPNcWQ&sig2=oLS16awUouU39N8eb1HY4A&bvm=bv.53537100,d.aWc)).  And I think that makes sense.

So now I'm left with trying to figure out how to represent file complexity.  My thought is that I should just use the maximum method CC for that file.

Any thoughts about that approach or any other suggestions?

Thanks!

Ken

Comment: You should probably head over to http://programmers.stackexchange.com. StackOverflow is meant for concrete issues.

Answer (score 4):

Few years ago I had the same question. I answered it in the following way and it worked and works for me perfectly:

The purpose to minimize complexity is to improve maintainability. Cyclomatic complexity is an indicator of logical complexity, and you are right - it is applied to the smallest 'unit', i.e. function. It is possible to derive 'summary' metrics, like total/max/min/etc but they rarely show something useful, when it is about cyclomatic complexity. I tried to use 'summary' metrics to compare 2 code bases, but concluded that only distribution graphs of cyclomatic complexity are really useful here.

So, what could be used to indicate something about maintainability level for bigger units/levels of abstractions, like files/components/subsystems? I found that the first metric is a size of a unit in lines of code. If you limit the size of a file, like 1000 lines, and limit cyclomatic complexity for each function in the file, you will have relatively "simple" file, because it is "small" and contains only "simple" functions. You may include or exclude comment/blank lines or count only statements or only executable lines...

However, I concluded that it does not really matter in this particular application. Just limit some 'size' metric and it will serve the purpose in most cases.. Later you may think about limiting the total number of lines of code per a component/subsystem. It will have the same effect - component is "simple", because it contains "small" number of "simple" files.

The post you referred to is very good. It can be extended to broader metric, which usually is named as 'maintainability index'. The index is very high if a function is complex, file is big and has got frequent changes, little coverage by tests, and so on (add here whatever you think defines maintainability). It is the best way, I know, to find hot-spots for re-factoring...

**Disclaimer:** I am looking after [Metrix++](http://metrixplusplus.sourceforge.net/) tool which executes the use case scenario, I explained above.

Comment: *`Few years ago I had the same question`* Was this the starting point of Metrix++? Is it still maintained (seems the homepage is new)?

Comment: This was not the starting point, I extended when I needed. I have not added new features last 2 years, but I just use it as it works and does what I need it to do.